# Navigating to a new optional base route while maintaining the current nested routes - Vue Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Please may someone help me with a params/named route question.

I'm trying to achieve an optional named route change at the first level while maintaining nested structure. Is there a way to achieve this using named routes?

For example imagine use case, either:
/europe/train
**or**
/car/europe/spain

I would have a new named route going to train instead of car and the behaviour to link to the full path of:
/train/europe/spain

Currently this takes you to the base route with the first level /train removing nested routes, you then need to reselect Europe and Spain.

This is the current setup I'm trying to achieve this:

```
path: '/:transportSlug?',
name: 'Transport',
...
children: [
    {
        path: ':regionSlug',
        name: 'Region',
        ...
        children: [
            {
                path: ':countrySlug',
                name: 'Country',
                ...
```

```
<router-link :to="{
    name: 'Transport',
    params: {
        transportSlug: filter.slug,
        regionSlug: region.slug,
        countrySlug: country.slug
    }
}">
```

This is passing in 3 params when navigating to a new base route and all 3 are being correctly passed. I can output them in the view which makes me think it may be a technical limitation/misunderstanding somewhere.

I'm aware of path routing and creating the full path with a computed properly.

[Example here](https://codepen.io/jacobwalters/pen/MWyONvm)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Posva from Vue I was able to solve this.

My approach and understanding of how Vue Router worked was slightly incorrect by thinking that you needed to reference the named route in a nested tree that you wanted to update.

To update the Transport type in /euope/spain I would need to instead reference the Country named route and update the param for the transport.

```
<router-link :to="{
    name: 'Country',
    params: {
        transportSlug: filter.slug,
    }
}">
```

This maintains the correct URL while updating the Transport type.

Hope this may be of some help to someone.